# finding element

Tags: java, string, comparison

I´ve got this method:

```
public User findById(String name) 
{
    for (User u : list) 
    {
        if (u.getFirstName() == name) 
        {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null; // or empty User
}
```

How can i program a method in my window class so that i can print out the user i´ve found?

This is what i got. (think im way off)

```
public void findCustomer()
{
    String firstname = findCustomerField.getText();

    if(!firstname.equals(""))
    {
        String result = list.findById(firstname);
        outputText.setText(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, besides that you shouldn't do a comparison using ==, but using .equals() in the first code example, it seems pretty okay. So what's not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `==` in your comparison

```
if (u.getFirstName() == name)
```

but `equal`

```
if (u.getFirstName().equal(name))
```

The operator `==` tests to see if two object reference variables refer to the exact same instance of an object.

The method `.equals()` tests to see if the two objects being compared to each other are equivalent

You need to change also your findCustomer method like this

```
public void findCustomer()
{
    String firstname = findCustomerField.getText();

    if(!"".equal(firstname))
    {
        User user = list.findById(firstname);
        if(user != null)
        {
            outputText.setText(user.getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I did this. In the findCustomer()method eclipse still tells me to change String result to User result. If I do this I can't setText with result   :-/

Comment: I edited my answer with the code to replace in the findCustomer method

Comment: ahh! Thanks a lot! Now I´m going to try to change the name to a customerID. Be back shortly with more problems;)

Comment: No problem ;) accept the answer if it solved your problem and feel free to post a new question ;)

Comment: Ok, one more quick question. Is there any easy way to remove the object(node) I´ve just found? I´m completely new to Java Collections. And I'm using arrayList not linkedList.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.equals()` for **value** equality check.

Change this to:

```
if (u.getFirstName().equals(name)) {
```

The `==` basically does object reference equality check.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = list.findById(firstname);
```

Your findById returns a User so change it to:

```
User result = list.findById(firstname);
```

Consequently change your next line to:

```
outputText.setText(result.getFirstName());
```